# How to add marker click listener in IONIC2?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working with IONIC2, i have implement map and put markers on the map.
I can get map click listener but can not get Marker click listener.

I had tried addlistener also but can not get click event for marker.

Here is my code for adding marker on map:

```
addMarkerOnMap(latLng1: GoogleMapsLatLng, depotsEntity: DepotsEntity) {
/**
 * To add marker in the map, need to initialize GoogleMapsMarkerOptions
 */
let options: GoogleMapsMarkerOptions = {
  icon: "www/img/location.png",
  title: depotsEntity.address,
  position: latLng1,
  animation: GoogleMapsAnimation.DROP
};
let marker = this.map.addMarker(options)
this.map.on(this.map.markerClicked, function () {
  console.log("markerClicked"); // This is not working yet

});
```

Please help me if anybody knows regarding marker click listener in IONIC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code I will assume that you are using [`cordova-plugin-googlemaps`](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps).

There are a couple of things you are doing wrong. The first is that `map.addMarker()` doesn't return a marker, instead it returns a promise with a value of type `GoogleMapsMarker` which makes this line incorrect

`let marker = this.map.addMarker(options)`

Secondly, you attach the event handler to the marker object and not to the map which means this bit is also wrong

```
this.map.on(this.map.markerClicked, function () { });
```

What you need to do is call `this.map.addMarker()`, wait until the promise is resolved, and add the click handler to the marker returned by the promise.

**Example**

```
this.map.addMarker(options).then((marker: GoogleMapsMarker) => {
        marker.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => { console.log('Marker clicked...'); });
});
```

You will need to make sure `GoogleMapsMarker` and `GoogleMapsEvent` have been imported from `ionic-native`.

**Note**

As of writing this I have theoretically showed you how to implement what you want but at the minute this is likely to give you the following error

> this._next is not a function

This is a known issue and as far as I can tell it happens on any map / marker event that you have to subscribe to. The issue can be tracked on the Ionic Native GitHub page [#206](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-native/issues/206).